# How to find the function of return map for the dynamical system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

The dynamic of the system is showed as below:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot x=y \\
\dot y =2\delta y-x+1\
\end{cases}$$
$$[x(t^+),y(t^+)]^T=[-x(t),0]^T\\ for \ x(t)<0 \ and \ y(t)=0, (0<\delta<1)$$
The typical chaotic attractor:

[image]

The exact piecewise solution of the above equation:
$$x(t)=e^{\delta t}\{\{x(0)-1\}cos(\omega t)+\frac1\omega \{y(0)-\delta x(0)+\delta\}sin(\omega t)\}+1$$
$$y(t)=e^{\delta t}\{y(0)cos(\omega t)+[\omega -\omega x(0)+\frac \delta\omega y(0)-{\delta^2\over\omega}x(0)+{\delta^2\over\omega}]sin(\omega t)\}$$
$$\omega =\sqrt {1-\delta^2}$$

The trajectory rotates divergently around the equilibrium point $(1, 0)$ and reaches the switching threshold at $t=\frac{2\pi}\omega$. A x−coordinate of the reaching point is obtained as $−e^{2πδ\over \omega}  + 1$ and as seen in the image above $-A+1$ by substituting $x(0)=0 \ and \ t=\frac{2\pi}\omega$ into the solution. Here I define the Poincare-section as below:
$$l\equiv \{(x,y)|y=0\}$$
How I can find the return map:
$$f:l\mapsto l,x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$
for this system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "How I can find the return map" Compute $y(t)$, solve $y(t)=0$, deduce $x(t)$ at this time $t$ in terms of $x(0)$, you are done.

Comment: @Did Please show me how can I do that with the dynamic system with switch condition like above.

Comment: ?? Simply follow the steps delineated in my first comment. Where is the problem? First, $y(t)=$ ...

Comment: I got $t$ after solving $y(t)=0$ as an arctan function of $x(0), y(0), \delta \ and \ \omega$. How can I do the next step? By substituting this $t$ into $x(t)$ and derive $x(0)$

Comment: Sorry but you should be focusing on your **first step**, which is to find a formula for $y(t)$. Where is this formula?

Comment: I thought $y(t)$ is just $\dot x$, am I right?

Comment: Again (and for the last time): your first step is to find an explicit formula for $y(t)$ as a function of $t$, $\delta$, $\omega$, $x_0$.

Comment: Sorry I has updated the solution for $y(t)$ above.

Comment: Right. Now you know that $y(0)=0$, this simplifies $y(t)$ somewhat. Do that, and you should be able to determine the first time $t>0$ such that $y(t)=0$ again (this is the second step of my initial comment).

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, I find that when $t={k\pi\over\omega}$, $y(t)$ return to 0, but I don`t know what exactly "deduce $x(t)$ at this time $t$ in terms of $x(0)$" mean. Can you elaborate on it? In the other hand, if $x(0)=1$, $y(t)$ always equal 0 when $y(0)=0$. Is it some kind of special case or something?

Comment: Again you are going too fast, with the consequence that you are lost. First remaining task: find the first time $t>0$ when $y(t)=0$. Call this time $T$. Second task to come: compute $x(T)$. So, what do you get for $T$ and $x(T)$? // Re the case $x(0)=1$, yes, you knew from the start this is a special case since $(x,y)=(1,0)$ is a fixed point.

Comment: Sorry I got $T=$$\pi\over\omega$ and $x(T)=e^{\delta\pi\over\omega}(1-x(0))+1$. Now what should I do?

Comment: "Now what should I do?" Rejoice, perhaps, since you are finished: the function $f$ such that $x(T)=f(x(0))$ is your return map, *by definition*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're my life saver! I think "the function $f$ such that $x(T)=f(x(0))$ is your return map, by definition" is what I really needed. Now if I change the Poincare-section like:
$$l\equiv \{(x,y)|-1<x<0, y=0\}$$
Should I just limit the above $x(T)$ into $-1<x<0$?

Comment: To return to $L^-=(x<0,y=0)$ starting from $L^-$, simply compose twice the return map from $L=(y=0)$ to $L$ which you just computed, starting from some point in $L^-$, since this map sends $L^-$ to $L^+=(x>0,y=0)$ and sends $L^+$ to $L^-$.

Comment: Does the function of $x(T)$ above suppose to have some kind of conditions? I've tried to simulate the above function but it seem to increase to infinity so I thought I would have to be a piece-wise function.

Comment: Of course iterating the function $f:\xi\mapsto e^{\delta\pi/\omega}(1-\xi)+1$ yields a sequence that goes to infinity since $f(\xi)-1=-a\cdot(\xi-1)$ with $a>1$.

Comment: There is a typo in one of my previous comments: use $L_-=(x<1,y=0)$ and $L_+=(x>1,y=0)$. Note additionally that $\ell=(-1<x<0,y=0)$ is not a Poincaré section since the image of $\ell$ by the return map to $L_-$ is $\ell'=(1-2a^2<x<1-a^2,y=0)$ and $\ell'$ is not included in $\ell$.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out till now. All I trying to do is find the return map for the Poincare section that mention in the op. The return map for $l\equiv \{(x,y)|-1<x<0, y=0\}$ is showed in page 3 of [this paper] but I can't explain why.
[this paper]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4X4exhfqAS6bkYyVWpWZW0za3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The dynamics is completely different from what you explained until now. One starts from $x_n$ in $(-1,0)$, then one follows the dynamical system starting from $(-x_n,0)$ until hitting the half line $(x<0,y=0)$ at $x_{n+1}$. Hence $x_{n+1}$ is the image of $-x_n$ by some varying number of iterations of the return map, as explained in (11). Two conclusions: you made everybody lose their time by reproducing only partially your source, which led us astray; the source explains quite clearly what they are doing, so what do you want more?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your precious time because of my stupidity. Please show me how can I obtain the similar return map like (11) with the Poincare-section $l\equiv \{(x,y)|y=0\}$ and the starting point is like in the paper $(-x_n,0)$. My guess is that it should have two interval like $0<x<\sqrt A+1$ with $\sqrt A+1$ is the reaching point when $x>0$ and the other interval is $-A+1<x<0$. And by substituting $x(0)=-x_n$ and $t=k\pi/\omega$ to the solution (8) and solve the border condition like in the paper, I can obtain the similar function. Again, sorry for bothering you this much.